# django serializer - how to pass datetime from DB to view - 'argument must be 9-item sequence, not datetime.datetime'

Tags: python, datetime, django-models, django-serializer

I want to format a `datetime.datetime` in the template with:

```
{{ script.lastrundate|date:'Y-m-d' }} {{script.lastrundate|time}}
```

but I found that the values generated by the serializer are all strings, not of their original type. When I just print them they are good; but if I want to format the date, I got empty string.

My model:

```
class TScript(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    category = ForeignKey(TCategory, PROTECT, null=False, blank=False, to_field='name') # protect TScript from deletion; TScript belongs to TCategory
    service = ForeignKey(TService, PROTECT, null=False, blank=False, to_field='name')
    platform = ForeignKey(TPlatform, PROTECT, null=False, blank=False, to_field='name')
    command = models.CharField(max_length=1024, blank=False, null=False)
    machine = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=False, null=False)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=False, null=False) # now save as string to avoid problem
    interval = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False) # seconds
    timeout = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False) # seconds
    status = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False)
    out = models.CharField(max_length=1024, blank=True, null=True)
    error = models.CharField(max_length=512, blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, null=True)
    lastrundate = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    insertDate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

My serializer:

```
class TScriptSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    lastrundate = serializers.DateTimeField() # I changed here but not working
    class Meta:
        model = TScript
        fields = ['id', 'category', 'service', 'platform', 
                  'command', 'machine', 'username', 'interval',
                  'out', 'error', 'timeout', 'status', 'description',
                  'lastrundate', 'insertDate']
```

My view methods:

```
@login_required
@csrf_protect
def scriptsList(request):
    logger.info("SCRIPTSLIST Start HTML")
    try:
        scripts=operationsDB.getScripts()
        return render(request, 'tablescripts.html', {"scripts":scripts})
    except Exception as e:
        tb = traceback.format_exc(1)
        logger.error('ERROR Exception in scriptsList, the error is: ' + repr(e) + " - args - " + repr(tb))
        errorMsg="Exception "+repr(e)
        result={"CausesError":errorMsg}
        return redirect('/scriptsList/?' + urllib.urlencode(result))
```

`operationsDB.getScripts()`:

```
def getScripts():
    arrScripts=[]
    try:
        scripts=TScript.objects.all()
        for script in scripts:
            serializedScript=TScriptSerializer(script)
            dataScript=serializedScript.data
            arrScripts.append(dataScript)
        return scripts
    except Exception as e:
        tb = traceback.format_exc(1)
        logger.error('ERROR Exception in getScripts; the error is: ' + repr(e) + " - args - " + repr(tb))
        return []
    return arrScripts
```

I don't get it.

EDIT: this error is about another wrongly formatted field, so not relevant.

<s>The error is:</s>

```
[12/Mar/2018 17:18:42]  ERROR  [scriptsList] - ERROR Exception in scriptsList, the error is: TypeError('argument must be 9-item sequence, not datetime.datetime',) - args - 'Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File "/var/www/html/ElasticSearch/frontEnd/views.py", line 876, in scriptsList\n    return render(request, \'tablescripts.html\', {"scripts":scripts})\nTypeError: argument must be 9-item sequence, not datetime.datetime\n'
```

Comment: I think removing this line will help you , `lastrundate = serializers.DateTimeField() `

Comment: Actually I didn't have it at the beginning.. I tried to add this line and no help.

Comment: Hmmm..... when I print more stacktraces I got more details..... It was about another field is not correctly formatted by `datetime.datetime.strftime()`. Now, the error is solved, but I still get string in the view. Let me update the question to remove the last part.

Comment: Try to pass formatted time to your template

Comment: Do you think when in `operationsDB.getScripts()`, I got strings? At last I solved it by setting the `DATE_TIME_FORMAT` in the `settings.py` to regulate the format of all datetime in the app, and got what I want, but it is not clear to me till now.